# Yii2. Подскажите, где USER узнает новых пользователей

Tags: php, yii2, ооп

Начинаю изучать Yii2 и ООП в целом, потому прошу без эмоций. 
Шаблон Basic. Хочу использовать свою таблицу clients, с бОльшим количеством полей, чем в yii-шной user. А авторизацию оставить как есть.
В модели USER описаны admin и demo. Подскажите, где USER узнает новых пользователей.
Хотел переписать статическую users вытащив в нее всех из базы, но статическим нельзя присаваивать значение функций.

Comment: что значит "узнает" и кто такой "USER"?

Comment: в yii2 компонент user не требует определенной таблички, вы можете ее определить сами, главное, чтобы модель, работающая с табличкой, реализовывала интерфейс IdentityInterface. С другой стороны вы можете сделать вторую табличку с нужными дополнительными полями и подтягивать их когда нужно, не трогая существующее решение